# SAS/SQL group by and keeping all rows

Tags: plsql, group-by, sas, proc-sql

I have a table like this, observing the behavior of some accounts in time, here two accounts with acc_ids 1 and 22:

```
acc_id   date    mob
  1      Dec 13   -1
  1      Jan 14    0
  1      Feb 14    1
  1      Mar 14    2
  22     Mar 14    10
  22     Apr 14    11
  22     May 14    12
```

I would like to create a column `orig_date` that would be equal to `date` if `mob=0` and to minimum `date` by `acc_id` group if there is no `mob=0` for that `acc_id`.

Therefore the expected output is:

```
acc_id   date    mob   orig_date
  1      Dec 13   -1     Jan 14
  1      Jan 14    0     Jan 14
  1      Feb 14    1     Jan 14
  1      Mar 14    2     Jan 14
  22     Mar 14    10    Mar 14
  22     Apr 14    11    Mar 14
  22     May 14    12    Mar 14
```

The second account does not have `mob=0` observation, therefore `orig_date` is set to `min(date)` by group.

Is there some way how to achieve this in SAS, preferably by one `proc sql` step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty simple. Just calculate the min date in two ways and use coalesce() to pick the one you want.

First let's turn your printout into an actual dataset.

```
data have ;
  input acc_id date :anydtdte. mob ;
  format date date9.;
cards;
1      Dec13   -1
1      Jan14    0
1      Feb14    1
1      Mar14    2
22     Mar14    10
22     Apr14    11
22     May14    12
;
```

To find the DATE when MOB=0 use a CAsE clause.  PROC SQL will automatically remerge the MIN() aggregate results calculated at the ACC_ID level back onto all of the detail rows.

```
proc sql ;
create table want as
select *
     , coalesce( min(case when mob=0 then date else . end)
               , min(date)
               ) as orig_date format=date9.
from have
group by acc_id
order by acc_id, date 
;
quit;
```

Result:

```
Obs    acc_id         date    mob    orig_date

 1        1      01DEC2013     -1    01JAN2014
 2        1      01JAN2014      0    01JAN2014
 3        1      01FEB2014      1    01JAN2014
 4        1      01MAR2014      2    01JAN2014
 5       22      01MAR2014     10    01MAR2014
 6       22      01APR2014     11    01MAR2014
 7       22      01MAY2014     12    01MAR2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a data step approach

```
data have;
input acc_id date $ mob;
datalines;
1  Dec13 -1
1  Jan14  0
1  Feb14  1
1  Mar14  2
22 Mar14  10
22 Apr14  11
22 May14  12
;

data want;
    do until (last.acc_id);
        set have;
        by acc_id;
        if first.acc_id then orig_date=date;
        if mob=0 then orig_date=date;
    end;
    do until (last.acc_id);
        set have;
        by acc_id;
        output;
    end;
run;
```